# Zend tool include path

Tags: php, unix, zend-framework, zend-tool

Is it possible to install and use ZF (+ its console tool) without access to include_path direcotory? I've tried adding the ...Zend/library direcotry into include_path but without success.

I did it this way:

```
php -r 'set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/var/www/.../Zend/library")';
```

After `var_dump`ing result of the function above it returned old include_path which should mean success. But next call of get_include_path() returned the **old** path too.

I've also tried to set the environment variable:

```
ZF_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND="/var/www/.../Zend/library"
```

There is our company framework in the old include_path directory so I can't (even if I could I should't) copy there the ZF library.

I think a proper framework shouldn't rely on any global PHP settings as include_path is. I think it should be possible to set the include path somewhere in ZF internal configuration file.

**edit:**
I added `set_include_path('/var/www/.../Zend/library')` into zf.php file and the tool stopped throwing 'wrong include_path' error. In fact it sopped printing any output. When executing command `zf create project test` it does nothing. ~/.zf folder wasn't created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't copy the zf library in some "global" include path, e.g. `/usr/share/php/`, you can still copy it where your project is and start the `zf` tool from there. A folder structure like:

```
/var/www/zf_tool
                `/bin/
                      `zf.sh
                      `zf.php
                `/library
                      `/Zend
```

Copy the `Zend` folder under library, and the `zf.sh` and `zf.php` scripts under `bin` and set them to be executable `chmod a+x zf.sh zf.php` if they are not already.
Next, if you run `/var/www/project/bin/zf.sh` it'll look for zf files in the include_path, but if it's not there, it'll go up one folder and go into the `library` folder. Only if the zf library is not to be found there, it'll die with an error. In the end, creating a new zf project is simple as:

```
$ pwd
/var/www/zf_tool/bin
$ ./zf.sh create project /var/www/test_project
```

That's it. HTH :)

Comment: I just tried your solution and it seems not to work. Script dies with the include path error.

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot the Zend directory. After creating it. It does not die with an error ... it just dies and does NOTHING :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using he set/get include_path functions is only going to set it for the life of the "request" so it goes back to normal as soon as the command/web request finishes. As far as setting the include path for your local copy you can do that in an environment variable as you tried or in your `~/.zf` folder on the box. there are configs in there and there is a setting cor include path.

Beyond that you could also ad something like what you had in the `php -r ...` to the shell script youre executing directly although this wouldnt be the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is no ~/.zf folder. Zend_tool always exited with error ("In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework is inside your include_path."...) So I think it was unable to create it. I added set_include_path() directly into zf.php file but it does not seem to work. (see question edit)