# Zend command line tool action error

Tags: php, unix, zend-framework, zend-tool

I just managed to create a project using Zend_Tool, but I am stuck on "second step" - enabling layout.

```
zf enable layout
```

leads to:

> An Error Has Occurred
>   Action 'enable' is not a valid action.

This is my folder structure:

```
|--library
|  |--Zend         //framework classes in this folder
|
|--bin             //command line tool folder
|  --zf.sh
|  --zf.php
|  --zf.exe
|
|--zend_test       //my test project folder
|  |--application
|  |--library
|  |  --Zend       //symlink to ../../library/Zend
|  |--public
|  |--tests
```

The library folder is in my include_path. Checked with:

```
php -i | grep include_path
```

Note that I was able to create the project with `zf create project zend_test` and other actions like `show` work.

There are some ppl on the official Zend Framework forum with same problem, but there are no answers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It was coincidence, what led to this error. At first I was unable to even run the tool because I couldn't set `include_path` (because of permissions). After that there was a problem with (most likely) out-of-date php. (original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088848/zend-tool-include-path))

After few hours of headache I deleted the tool and left ZF for a while. Two days ago I wanted to try that on updated server, but coulnd't find the tool so I downloaded it again. Unfortunatelly (for me) Zend released new version of framework and I extracted only the tool.

**Briefly**
 
There was a mismatch in versions of the tool (`bin`) and the framework (`library`) or possibly the `library` folder was corrupted.

**Solution**
Download and extract the whole ZF again to make sure the versions match and files are not corrupted. Also double check the include_path with `php -i | grep include_path`

Answer (score 1):

I've download zf.bat from

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/bin/

Revision 21133

This is the latest version, as my zend server... why can't I run  commands such as:

zf enable layout

zf configure db-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Heey,

I got exatly the same problem with XAMP.

It seems that Frankie-T's idea is good, because I renamed `c:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend to Zend_` and also `c:\xampp\php\zf.bat` and `c:\xampp\php\zf.php` to `zf.bat_ zf.php_`.

Of course I have my ZF library downloaded to `c:\xampp\htdocs\zf\` and my Path set to `C:\xampp\htdocs\zf\bin;`

Now if I run the folloving command, I get this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\login>zf show version
Zend Framework Version: 1.10.5
```

Now I have `zf enable layout` as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tnx, this helped me a lot...  I have old version if xampp

Answer (score 1):

Zend also comes with XAMPP package. So, it is generally becoming a version mismatch. XAMPP's Zend version may be older. So, just rename or delete the Zend folder in \xampp\php\PEAR. and it will start working.

http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/11/zend-framework-creating-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with a xampp 1.7.3 setup.
I downloaded the whole Framework again, checked the entries in PATH. The problem stayed the same.

[Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775207/problems-with-zend-tool-reporting-that-providers-are-not-valid) brought the solution for me, as I encountered another strange behavior of a version mismatch when typing "zf show version".

The problem comes with the xampp installation - it ships with an older version of zend.

You need to override the files in XAMPP/php/PEAR/zend with the ones from the new library you just downloaded.

Hope this helps.