# provider "project" is not a valid provider

Tags: zend-framework, xampp, zend-tool

whn i creating  a project on command console i`m getting some error in zend  Framework 1.11 i also set my environment varibale flowing way.

Download zendframe work extract and paste into D:\xampp\php\

```
1st->  enviernment valriable set -> name: Path : .;D:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin;D:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\;D:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat

2nd-> System Path D:\xampp\php\

3rd->Copy zend folder from D:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library into paste D:\xampp\php\PEAR
Php.ini

4th -> include_path = ".;D:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework\library;D:\xampp\php\PEAR"

5th -> then create project on command-> D:\xampp\htdocs->zf create project ProjectName
```

please give me the respone to seem the error ASASP.
thanks
Bikash ranajn

Comment: And what's the error? Maybe a bit important.

Comment: Hi i`m getting the error is: "provider “project” is not a valid provider" when i create project on console command ->zf  create project proname

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with zend-tool reporting that providers are not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775207/problems-with-zend-tool-reporting-that-providers-are-not-valid)

Comment: Hi i already replace and error has same came

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research for you I did find the problem of Zend Tool in combination with XAMPP.

Please copy `zf.bat` and `zf.php` to the folder `D:\xampp\php`. After that it should do the trick.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ronn0  i hv another question how can i secure my .htaccess file already hack by 2014reltimes.ru

Comment: On your local machine? You can try running Microsoft Essensials and Malware Bytes. Please be sure to start with a new installation of Xampp and Zend after that, i guess otherwise it'll happen again.